# How to identify self referencing loop?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a below model from the EF entity:

```
public partial class Commodity
{
    public Commodity()
    {
        this.CommodityVarieties = new HashSet<CommodityVariety>();
    }

    public int CommodityID { get; set; }
    public string CommodityName { get; set; }
    public string CommodityVarietyDisplayName { get; set; }
    public string BackColor { get; set; }
    public string ForeColor { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CommodityVariety> CommodityVarieties { get; set; }

}

public partial class CommodityVariety
{
    public int VarietyID { get; set; }
    public int CommodityID { get; set; }
    public string VarietyName { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

    public virtual Commodity Commodity { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get a list of commodities and convert that list to JSON string using `Newtonsoft`. Hence, I write

```
DbContext context = new DbContext();
var list = context.Commodities.ToList();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

I am getting below error:

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'Commodity' with type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Commodity_B55D25F995ED72E0B75FED715153713965D91EB5A3BF576322FE6DEAC130C0F5'.
>   Path '[0].CommodityVariety[0]

I know it is because of the reference to `Commodity` in the `CommodityVariety` class.

To avoid I updated JSON Serializing Setting to have `ReferenceLoopHandling` to `Ignore` like below:

```
options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

Above settings give me

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

I have tried all the possible answers from the StackOverflow.

Finally, I did

```
public DbContext() : base("name=DbContextEntity")
{
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
}
```

Now, I get the code running without any error and `Commodity.CommodityVarieties` is null.

I have so many foreign keys and it is really hard to map them all manually after setting `ProxyCreationEnabled` to `false`.

Is there any way to identify self-referencing before JSON serializing and make it null? Like below:

```
DbContext context = new DbContext();
var list = context.Commodities.ToList();

//filter only properties of `Commodity` property and find object of type `Commodity`
//var suspectObjects = list.Any(x => x.OfType<Commodity>()).ToList();
//suspectObjects.ForEach(item => { item = null; });

//I know the above segment will not work. I seek your help and I thought something like above explain more to you what I want actually.

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. basically, most often Database model is not suited for being serialized to JSON. That's why there's often a mapping layer that translated structures from DB into API structures.

Anyways..

Nullifying the "offending" reference is one way to solve the problem, but if your ORM (EF, NH, XPO, whatever) tracks changes, you now get a risky situation: what if someone/something **commits** the changes afterwards? You'll save a lots of NULLs to the DB and break your data.

The JSON serializer that you are using, most probably Newtonsoft (judging from JsonConvert class) most probably offers you a configuration switch that will decide what to do when a circular reference is found in the serialized object graph. Check the docs.

For example, if you are using Newtonsoft's, then try [ReferenceLoopHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm)

You can also use attributes or settings to make the serializer ignore certain properties. In the example you provided, excluding `CommodityVariety.Commodity` would break the reference loop and solve the problem as well. Parent class has a collection of children, children no longer care about the parent, everything's fine for JSON. However, after DEserializing, you may need to manually fix the child-to-parent back-references back.

You can also implement and add your own plugins for the serializer and completely define the serialization however you like, that a sure-fire solution, but quite an overkill for this problem here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` and since I have my properties, I ended up with 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

Comment: I would like to find all the properties (including child properties) that refer to the parent class (in my case 'Commodity') and make it null before serializing. I strongly believe this way I can get rid of Self Referencing loop error and out of memory exception.

Comment: Mostly, my database objects are stable and not updated very often. Hence, I chose to nullify the self-references before serializing.

Comment: Hence, my question is how to nullify the "offending" reference?

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq: Unfortunatelly, I'm out of time right now. Please take my advice: if you only want to serialize that data and if you dont have any other idea than null'ing the references, then please stick to `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`. It effectively does what you want: it nullifies any references that already were seen up in the tree of objects. If OutOfMemory is thrown when you use that option, then it most probably will be thrown as well with your custom null'ifying. Most probably OOM is thrown due to some other cause. Use that `Ignore` and focus on diagnosing OutOfMemory first.

Comment: For example: maybe just the amout of data is so huge that it produces OOM and you have to deal with it? Or maybe you set the Ignore flag in one place, and something else is serialized with circular references and ends up serializing the same things again and again?

Comment: And answering "how": pick the root object, add its reference to HashSet<object>.Call it "visited objects" etc. Use reflection to find this objects fields/properties. Iterate over those fields/properties, read their values. Check each value if it is in the visited objects hashset. If it is, nullify it via reflection via field/prop.SetValue. Then, iterate over those fields/props again, and add that value to a hashset, get its fields/properties, check them in hashset and maybe nullify, and so on, recursively.